# is it possible to monkey patch list literal in Python?

Tags: python

I'd like to do something like this

```
import builtins


class HackedList(list):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        pass # my code here

builtins.list_literal = HackedList # there is no such thing as list_literal, only list which seems to have no effect on literal itself
```

I need to override builtin, not to subclass.

Comment: When you say list literal, do you mean you want to override something like `a = []`, such that `[]` returns something not a list? If so, you might want to make your question clearer.

Comment: Yep, I need just that.